# Setting UIProgressView progress to 0

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I have a UIProgressView which runs for 2.5 seconds however sometimes, like if the app is being resumed from multitasking, the loading bar will start halfway up. How would I reset the UIProgressView to 0.0 each time it is opened? I could set to 0 in the `viewDidLoad` and then start the timer and animate it in the `viewDidAppear`. I just need to know how I can set my `progressView` to 0.

Comment: Can you give an example of which actions would update the UIProgressView?

Also i'd recommend setting it on the `viewWillAppear:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it on the `viewWillAppear`, thats what it calls when the view will be displayed whether when you push it into the hierarchy ro when you resume from the background.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super viewWillAppear();
    self.progressView.progress = 0.f;
}
```

You can also use the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

```
//inside init
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateProgressBar", name: UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil);

//on dealloc
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);


//the update method
func updateProgressBar() {
    self.progressBar.progress = 0.f;
}
```

Comment: Didn't saw the `Swift` in the title, updated the language.

Comment: Ok thanks - will give it a go and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: all I did was use the code: `self.progressView.progress = 0.0;` as the bar itself is animated in a function outside the `viewDidLoad`